# Evaluate assign function using hash

Tags: scheme, racket

This is part of an interpreter assignment I have.

When calling the following:

```
(evaluate (sp-assign "y" (sp-val 18)) (hash "x" 42))
```

I am trying to get this result:

```
'(18 . #hash(("y" . 18) ("x" . 42)))
```

Here's my relevant code:

```
(define empty-env (hash))
  (struct sp-var (varname))
  (struct sp-assign (var exp))

(define (evaluate prog env)
  (match prog
  [(struct sp-val (v))              (cons v env)] 
  [(struct sp-assign (var exp))     (eval-assign var exp env)]
  [(struct sp-var (varname))        (cons (hash-ref env varname) env)]
  [_                                (error "Unrecognized expression")]))

(define (eval-assign var exp env)
  evaluate (sp-var var) (hash var (evaluate exp env))) ;'((18 . #hash(("x" . 42))) . #hash(("y" . (18 . #hash(("x" . 42))))))
   ;var (hash var (evaluate exp env)) ;var (hash var (evaluate exp env))
)
```

The results that I am getting are respectively next to the two attempts that I have in the function (I've made far more attempts, but these are the closest I've gotten to what the actual result is supposed to be). Could someone please lend me a hand and let me know where I am going wrong with my logic?

EDIT: I was able to get a bit closer to my goal with the following implementation of eval-assign:

```
(list (car(evaluate exp env))(hash var (car(evaluate exp env))) env)
```

Which produces:

```
'(18 #hash(("y" . 18)) #hash(("x" . 42)))
```

But I'm still stuck with an extra hash in there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`hash-set`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._hash-set%29%29): *Functionally extends `hash` by mapping `key` to `v`, overwriting any existing mapping for `key`, and returning the extended hash table.*

```
(define (eval-assign var exp env)
  (let ((val (evaluate exp env)))
    (cons (car val) (hash-set env var (car val)))))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the problem. I wish I could do that. But for the purpose of the class, our professor is telling us that we should consider hash tables immutable. So we are not allowed to use set.

Comment: But the `hash-set` function doesn't mutate. It works on immutable hash tables.

Comment: Hmm I just looked at my notes, and I do have an example of hash-set in there. Plus, it doesn't have the exclamation point. I arrived at the same solution you have, just uglier because I didn't use let. I'll ask my professor if we can use hash-set. If yes, I'll consider this problem solved. For now, have an upvote. Thank you for the help!

Comment: There are two types of hash tables in Racket. If you use hash-set then you are working with immutable hash tables. As far as I can recall the immutable hash tables are currently implemented using splay trees.

Comment: I've never heard of splay trees before, but it looks like it's okay for me to use hash-set in this assignment.

Answer (score 1):

I made a few changes to `evaluate` and `eval-assign`.

```
(define empty-env (make-hash '()))
(struct sp-var (varname))
(struct sp-assign (var exp))
(struct sp-val (v))

(define (evaluate prog env)
  (match prog
    [(struct sp-val (v))              (cons v env)] ; Self evaluating 
    [(struct sp-assign (var exp))     (eval-assign var exp env)]
    [(struct sp-var (varname))        (cons (hash-ref env varname) env)]
    [_                                (error "Unrecognized expression")]))

(define (eval-assign var exp env)
  (let ((val (evaluate exp env)))

    (hash-set! env var (car val))
    (cons (car val) env)))
```

It should work as expected. Make sure when you test it to pass a mutable hash as empty environment, hence created with `make-hash`.

```
> (evaluate (sp-assign "y" (sp-val 18)) (make-hash (list (cons "x" 42))))
'(18 . #hash(("x" . 42) ("y" . 18)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have a slight problem with your solution though. We aren't allowed to use any variation of set! in the course. Is there a substitution that I can make for it? Also, I can't modify the call to the function (that's how my program will be evaluated) so I can't use your make-hash method.